# How to get the following table?

Tags: tables

I want to make this table: [image]

Whereas, I get this one: [image]
Any suggestions for the code I wrote below?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|c|}
& $A$ & NOT $A$ & SUM\\ \hline
$B$ & $P(A$ AND$\,B)$ & $P($NOT $A$ AND$\,B)$ & $P(B)$\\ 
NOT $B$ &$P(A\,$NOT$\,B)$ &$P($NOT $A\,$AND NOT$\,B)$ & $P($NOT $B)$ \\ \hline
& $P(A)$ & $P($NOT $A)$& $1$\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can the text font not be the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With no additional packages (I am assuming that Comic Sans is not your dream):

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}& $A$ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{ NOT $A$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{ SUM}\\ 
%\hline
\cline{2-4}
$B$ & $P(A$ AND$\,B)$ & $P($NOT $A$ AND$\,B)$ & $P(B)$\\ 
NOT $B$ &$P(A\,$NOT$\,B)$ &$P($NOT $A\,$AND NOT$\,B)$ & $P($NOT $B)$ \\ 
%\hline
\cline{2-4}
& $P(A)$ & $P($NOT $A)$& $1$\\ 
%\hline
\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is easy with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, blkarray}

\begin{document} 

\[ \everymath{\displaystyle}\setlength{\BAextrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{blockarray}{cccc}
    & A & \text{NOT }A & \text{SUM} \\
    \BAhhline{~---}
    \begin{block}{c|cc|c|}
    B & P(A\text{ AND}B) & P(\text{NOT }A\text{ AND }B) & P(B)\\
    \text{NOT }B &P(A\text{ NOT }B) &P(\text{NOT }A\text{ AND NOT }B) & P(\text{NOT }B) \\
    \BAhhline{~|---|}
    & P(A) & P(\text{NOT }A)& 1\\
    \BAhhline{~---}
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please use `\text{}` for SUM.

Comment: @corvus_192: Oh! yes, I forgot this cell. It's fixed. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Use `\multicolumn` command to suppress vertical ruling of specific cells. If the table width is not as you want, try to modify the width provided in `{\textwidth}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{table*}

    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.3\hsize}C |>{\hsize=1.5\hsize} C>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}C| >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C|}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A^{'}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SUM}
    \\
    \Xcline{2-4}{0.2mm}
        $B$ & $P(A \text{ AND } B)$ & $P(\text{NOT } A \text{ AND } B)$ & $P(B)$
    \\ 
        $B^{'}$ & $P(A \text{ AND NOT } B)$ & $P(\text{NOT } A \text{ AND NOT} B)$ & $P($NOT $B)$
    \\
    \Xcline{2-4}{0.2mm}
        & $P(A)$ & $P($NOT $A)$& $1$
    \\
    \Xcline{2-4}{0.2mm}
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table*}


\end{document}
```